# DEMANTRA 12.2.3 Installation

Tags: java, oracle

I am having a 64 bit machine with Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise where I need to install demantra 12.2.3.

1. Which JRE version (1.4 or higher) is compatible with it?
2. Is the version of the database 11.2.0.4.0 compatible?

Answer (score 0):

Version 1.4 is ancient stuff, 11gR2 itself comes with much newer versions.

Download is free, why don't you download and see ?